# Initializing a mutable static variable at runtime using a function which cannot be declared as static

Tags: rust, ffi, lifetime

```rust
use std::sync::Once;

struct Store;

impl Store {
    fn new() -> Store {
        Store {
            manifest: RwLock::new(/* ... */), // @note: RwLock does not implement Clone
        }
    }

    fn save(&mut self) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Failing code:

```rust
static mut store: Option<Store> = None;
static INIT: Once = Once::new();

unsafe {
    INIT.call_once(|| {
        store = Some(Store::new());
    });
    store.unwrap().save(); // Error: cannot move out of static item `store`
}
```

The error is straightforward, yet this is something I desperately need to accomplish because `Store::new()` does a ton of computationally expensive work under the hood.

I'm asking for the seemingly impossible: declare a static variable of type `Store` and initialize it at runtime – given that `new` cannot be `static` due to absolutely critical interior mutability that occurs within that function. Additionally, `RwLock` is a requirement and cannot be cloned. Dare I even ask whether this can be done in a way that is thread-safe?

There is no deferring the `new` function call or its internal properties as subsequent function calls in my program (which are otherwise irrelevant) rely on it.

To help make the problem more clear, this is within the context of FFI. I do not have much control over the program's lifetime or the ability to manage this variable in a safer way. Although, I definitely want this `Store` variable to live for the duration of the program's lifetime!

My question is conceptual. I am not by any means expecting this exact code to be slightly modified and suddenly compile. I'm asking a question here because I cannot wrap my head around how I can achieve what I want. I have tried several other methods... this is the best attempt I've made so far.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that you want to have a `static` variable which initialization is fairly complex? And you are fine with only running that initialization some time before the first access happens? *Or* do you require your static to be initialized before `main` runs?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt there is no main, this is ffi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure what do you want without an MCVE, but here is what I've managed to make.

First of all, your problem, as it is stated by the compiler, is quite straightforward: `unwrap` consumes the Option, and you can't consume the static. However, what do you really seem to want is to mutate the store in-place, and this is possible, AFAIK even in several ways.

The one I've chosen is following. In general, to mutate something in-place, we must get an exclusive reference to it. According to Option's docs, there is [`as_mut` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut), which converts `&mut Option<T>` into `Option<&mut T>`. The important part is that this new Option is *owned*, i.e. it is *not* stored in static (it references the static instead), and so it *can* be consumed by `unwrap`, yielding the necessary `&mut` reference, on which we can call `save`:

```
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        INIT.call_once(|| {
            store = Some(Store::new());
        });
        store.as_mut().unwrap().save();
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8eca38517fb2d437682dea1a3e4c639d) with possible implementation of your goal.

---

However, I'm not quite sure if your usage of `static mut` is justified. First of all, it's entirely unclear why do you need to use `&mut self` in `save`: if the only thing you have in `Store` is the `RwLock`, you'd be just fine with the shared reference, because, well, that's the point of locking. And in this case you could simply store the `Store` (pun unintended) in `lazy_static`:

```
// skipping definitions

use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref store: Store = Store::new();
}

fn main() {
    store.save();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f2dec761a8a83175284ff822448e680c)

Comment: the first portion of your answer is what I needed. Specifically `as_mut`. As far as my justification for mutability... its out of my control due to a 3rd party library  enforcing that requirement.